# How to load images in folder opencv&&qt c++

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

i wanna load images in folder.

```
 QString fileName = QFileDialog::getOpenFileName(this,
  tr("Open Images"), "C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures/pic.jpg", tr("Image Files (*.png   *.jpg *.bmp)"));
  ui->label_pic->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(fileName));
```

there is no problem code above or i can do that imread function but i wanna load pictures in folder one by one.For example;if there is 50 .jpg images in folder i wanna print screen one by one.

```
 QString fileName2;

 QString directory = QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(this,tr("Find Files"), QDir::currentPath());
//directoryComboBox->setCurrentIndex(directoryComboBox->findText(directory));

 ui->directoryComboBox->addItem(directory);
```

if i select C:/Users/Public/Pictures/Sample Pictures,i wanna show all picture on screen.

Comment: and what's stopping you?

Comment: If your problem is to get a list with "all" files/images from a single directory, have a look at this (I googled, hope thats the right functionality): https://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.7/qdir.html#entryList I guess you can add file extension filters too...

Comment: opencv has a glob() function for this, too. then there's hconcat and  vconcat to join the images.

Comment: i can't take images particularly in folder.if There is a loop like foreach,i wanna learn it.

Comment: @Otantic, go at it 1 problem at a time, not 3 problems at once.

Answer (score 1):

Use `QDir::entryList` to obtain a list of files in a directory matching your criterion (images) and then use `foreach`:

```
 QDir dir(directory);
 dir.setNameFilters(QStringList() << "*.png" << "*.jpg");
 QStringList fileList = dir.entryList();
 foreach (QString path, fileList)
 {
   // do what you want, for example, create a new QLabel here
 }
```

Comment: it seems possible but i can't do that.                            QImage image(fileList);
ui->label_pic2->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image2));

Comment: It is another question. You said that you can't get files in a directory "i can't take images particularly in folder.".

Comment: Of course, you can't load all images at once that's why there is a `foreach`. Load them one by one and then create a new QLabel for each or append them in one QPixmap. If you need help on this ask new questions.

Comment: look here for combining images  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6477958/qt-is-there-any-class-for-combine-few-images-into-one

Comment: fileList keep address like a.jpg,b.jpg,c.jpg...but i can't show on screen these images.Only their names is shown on screen.

Comment: How did you show their names on screen?

Comment: It will show you all images: `QLabel* label = new QLabel; label->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(path)); layout()->addWidget(label);`

Comment: i converted QstringList to QString and use printf() and it show the names of all images in folder.i only wanted to try how was work.